# How to take ScreenShots of C# Exceptions through Programming?

Tags: c#-3.0

I know how to take a Screen Shots through Programing but i want to take ScreenShots of the Exceptions Which I show in a messagebox appear runtime? Is it possible to do? please Suggest me...Thanks in Advance

```
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);    
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);    
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);    
bitmap.Save("c:\\screenshot.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I want to save MessageBox which contains Exceptions detail as bmp image. how to do it i have written this code in catch{ block}

Comment: why screenshots and not just the exception content?

Comment: What to generate a report with attachment of screenshot and want to mail automatically!

Comment: I may repeat myself: What's not working?

Comment: Are you trying to take a screenshot of the messagebox only? It looks like your code grabs the whole screen.

Comment: But more importantly, are you really sure you want to do this at all? Email a report with `ex.ToString()` instead of a screenshot -- it will be FAR more useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a screenshot of a message box created using `MessageBox.Show()`, it's going to be a bit tricky. Here are several options:

1. Skip the screenshot and capture the content of the error instead, using `ex.ToString()` (where `ex` is your `Exception` object).
2. Create a custom message box form so you can grab its size and position for your screenshot.
3. Use the title of the message box to find its handle and see if you can get its position and size. Frankly, I'm not sure this will work at all.

Also, keep in mind that `MessageBox.Show()` is modal. If you put your screenshot code after this line, the message box will be gone before your code runs. You can work around this with a thread, but that's also probably more work than it's worth, and may be unreliable due to timing issues.

Personally, I would recommend just using the content of the error and skipping the screenshot. It will be far more useful, and can include information you don't want to show the user in the message box.